# Pip Range Pinning and Constraints with Local Version Only

Tags: python, pip

We have some internally patched versions of some OSS packages, republished with [local version identifiers](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/specifications/version-specifiers/#local-version-identifiers), and an extra pip index where these are hosted. Is it possible to specify using either requirements file or pip constraints so that pip only resolves packages with this identifier? For example, if we have an oss package `some_package` published with version `3.2.0`, we might have extra packages published that include `3.2.0.0+internal`, `3.2.0.1+internal`, etc.

I would like to resolve some requirement such as `some_package>=3.2.0` but also include the requirement we only resolve versions with this local version identifier. Is there any clear cut way to do this with range pinning? I can do `some_package==3.2.0.0+internal`, but ideally would like a little more flexibility in my specification. And if there is some OSS version that meets the range intent but doesn't specify the local identifier, it should not be resolved as a valid version. Any recommendations?